# LibGdx: Utilizing gestures along with mouse input

Tags: java, input, libgdx, gesture

In my libgdx project i have a gesture listener and an Input processor utilized in separate classes. One inside the player one inside the main state. If i assign one of them as the input processor: `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor();` then i will not be able to aquire input from the other.

I tried to use the input multiplexer:

```
InputMultiplexer multi = new InputMultiplexer();

GestureHandler gesture = new GestureHandler();
InputProccessor input =  new InputProcessor();

multi.addProcessor(new GesturDetector(gesture));
multi.addProcessor(new GestureDetector(input);

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multi);
```

This didn't work and caused the game to crash. I would prefer to avoid the multiplexer. Is there anyway to check both input methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Multiplex is the right answer for your problem.

One thing often overlooked with a multiplexer is that the return value of your handlers (true or false) is very important.  (Its ignored without a multiplexer).  The result says whether you've "handled" the input or not.  Handled events will not be propagated to the next processor in the multiplexer.  Additionally, by default stub methods created by Eclipse will return 'true' which doesn't help.

In any event, this shouldn't crash.

Comment: I have one class implementing both the InputProcessor and the GestureDetector. When i write multiplexer.addProccessor(this); it is only adding the input so gestures still don't work.

Comment: Ah, yeah the `InputMultiplexer` needs two distinct objects.  Easiest hack may be to just make a new `GestureDetector` object that just forwards its calls to your original object.

Comment: I am sorry to be an annoyance but how would i do that?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure on the specifics (did you really implement a `GestureDetector` and not a `GestureListener`?  I think you want a Listener?)  But, generally: create a new class that overrides all the methods of interest, and in each method it just calls the same method on your combo inputprocessor/gesturedetector object.  Now you can register this delegate with the InputProcessor.  Its a bit of hack ...

Comment: Thanks for all your help unfortanate that they don't have an interface that takes care of gestures and mouse input.